# Socket closed unexpectedly

Tags: java, sockets, socketexception, connectionexception

I am writting a test program for a server. At the test app, I try to connect a great number of clients to the server, but after a while a get all kind of errors like these :

```
Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

or

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

or

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I use a new socket for every client I connect to the server.

Could someone enlighten me about this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you haven't provided much details of your server's nature. I suppose you are writing a typical TCP server. In this answer I will *not* talk about any Java-specific details.

The short advice is: insert a delay between clients connections. Without it you are actively simulating a DoS attack to your server.

For the longer one, read below.

Usually a TCP server creates only 1 *listening* socked by calling (in lovely C interface) `int sockfd = socket(...)` function, and passing the result (`sockfd` in our case) to `bind()` and `listen()` functions. After this preparations, the server would call an `accept()` which will steep the server in slumber (if the socket was marked as blocking) and if a client on the other side of the Earth will start calling a `connect()` function, than `accept()` (on the server side) with the support of the OS kernel will create *the connected socket*.

The actual number of possible *pending connectins* can be known by looking at the `listen()` function. `listen()` has a *backlog* parameter which defines the maximum number of connection the *OS kernel* should queue to the socket (this is basically a sum of all connections in `SYN_RCVD` and `ESTABLISHED` states). Historically the recommended value for *backlog* in 1980s was something like 5 which is obviously miserable in our days. In FreeBSD 7.2, for example, a *hard limit* for *backlog* may be guessed by typing:

```
% sysctl kern.ipc.somaxconn
kern.ipc.somaxconn: 128
```

and in Fedora 10:

```
% cat /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn
128
```

P.S.
Sorry for my terrible English.

Comment: I understood what you want to say....and actually that's what I 've done. Still the problem persists, and I cannot test my server on a very big number of clients, simply because I get an error eventually.

Answer (score 0):

There are OS and webserver limits how fast and how many connection you can start/accept. If you want to do performance testing on the server, try Apache JMeter as it has solutions to these limits.

Answer (score 0):

Your web/app server can only service a finite amount of clients at a time.

You will receive a connection refused/reset when this limit is reached.

Hope that answers your question.

Cheers